# How to use SharedPreferences with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have a class that extends BroadcastReceiver that shows if the wifi connection is connected or lost. I am trying to use SharedPreferences to pass this information to another activity but its not working. Is there a special way of setting up SharedPreferences in a BroadcastReceiver class? Please see my code below:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    protected SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    public static final String PREF_WIFI = "wifi";



    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = 
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    context.getApplicationContext());




        String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        mPrefs.edit().putString(PREF_WIFI, status).commit();


    }

}
```

I have even tried to set up mPrefs like below but still no luck

```
mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_WIFI, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
```

Comment: Consider that Receivers lifetime is so little and that this maybe causing your problem!

Comment: @Pavlos: both BroadcastReceiver and Activity execute on UI thread. This issue may appear if the activity is launched before the broadcast receiver is executed. @cv82: Why don't you call `NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);` from Activity's `onCreate` method instead of passing this info from broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Activity is part of the same application as the Receiver, it might be easier to subclass inside the Activity:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver wifiBR = null;
    // All the usual things

    // And add in
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // EVerything else

        wifiBR = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
                String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
                wifiChanged(status);
            }
        };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_THE_ONE_YOU_WANT);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_THE_OTHER_ONE_YOU_WANT);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AND_SO_ON);
    this.registerReceiver(wifiBR, filter);
    }

    // And add in
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (wifiBR != null) this.unregisterReceiver(wifiBR);
    }

    private void wifiChanged(String status) {
        // Does something based on status
    }
}
```

If there are multiple Activities, it would be clearer to have one of these per activity and to create and remove the receiver in `onResume` and `onPause` respectively and also put the information in shared preferences which are read in `onResume`. Or simply query the wifi state in `onResume` and then set up a receiver.

If there are multiple applications, then you are going to need to not only change some preferences, (which are publicly visible), you will also need to tell the other App's Activities that a change has been made. It would be easier for that app. to have it's own Broadcast Receivers.